# How to identify a pattern using Pandas on similar row names

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing an excel file with somewhat similar Vendor names and using agg function to add spend and then using sort function to sort the spend. Eventually, this data-frame is feeding onto a dynamic Bokeh plot.
I have vendor names which are minutely different due to the text format and my pandas data-frame is not recognizing this pattern when adding the spend. Despite the fact that its the same vendor I am not getting a holistic view of spend but missing some data and ultimately not getting counting in Bokeh plot.

## Data

```
Vendor    Site    Spend
ABC INC   A        300
ABC,Inc   B        100
ABC,Inc.  C        50
ABC,INC.  D        10
```

## Expected Result

All the data should add up to 460.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deal with punctuation, spaces, and caps vs lower before trying to get your sum but it will change the name of your Vendor in the output:

```
df.groupby([x.upper().replace(' ', '').replace(',','').replace('.','') for x in df['Vendor']])['Spend'].sum()

ABCINC    460
```

You could also modify the column name in place before calling the groupby:

```
df['Vendor'] = df['Vendor'].str.upper().str.replace(' ', '').str.replace(',','').str.replace('.','')
print(df.groupby('Vendor')['Spend'].sum())
```

The df now looks like:

```
   Vendor Site  Spend
0  ABCINC    A    300
1  ABCINC    B    100
2  ABCINC    C     50
3  ABCINC    D     10
```

and the output:

```
ABCINC    460
```

Comment: That's fine at the end of the day even it says "abc inc" with all necessary data summed up I am good.